# Vue: How does vuetify make its components available without import?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

When using the [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com) framework, there are a collection of components (like the slider, etc) that are available without being explicitly imported.

I'm curious how does vuetify accomplishes this?

Comment: If you look the [source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/index.ts), it installs itself as a plugin and runs `Vue.use(` and putting all components there.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense now

Comment: @Phiter Make it an answer and I'll accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/index.ts).

It installs itself as a plugin and runs `Vue.use(` and puts all components there.

```
import { Vuetify as VuetifyPlugin, VuetifyUseOptions } from 'types'

const Vuetify: VuetifyPlugin = {
  install (Vue: VueConstructor, args?: VuetifyUseOptions): void {
    Vue.use(VuetifyComponent, {
      components,
      directives,
      ...args
    })
  },
```